# AndroidView in Compose loses touch events in NestedScrollView

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, android-scrollview

I have a normal XML view with a LinearLayout inside a NestedScrollView. Inside there is a normal View and a Composable view which contains an AndroidView.

The layout:

```
<NestedScrollView ...>
    <LinearLayout ...>
       <View .../> <!-- click listener works properly -->
       <androidx.compose.ui.platform.ComposeView .../> <!-- click in inner AndroidView doesn't work properly -->
    </LinearLayout>
</NestedScrollView>
```

The ComposeView is set like this:

```
composeView.setContent {
    AndroidView(factory = {
        TextView(it).apply {
            setText("View in Compose")
            setOnClickListener { } // This breaks the scroll
        }
    })
}
```

When tapping the View inside a Compose the scroll doesn't work. The click listener eats all touch events.

Is there any way to make Android View click inside Compose behave correctly?

Comment: I am sorry, I mistake the scroll view class. I used the NestedScrollView. It is reported that Compose & View interoperability is not yet supported with it: https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/interop/compose-in-existing-ui

Comment: Chris banes has posted a workaround in the issue tracker, I answered to a related issue  here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/70195667/1128600

Answer (score -1):

Usually there is a `Boolean` exposed called as `requireUnconsumed` in all such cases. I'm not really sure about the particular implementation since it concerns interop, not something that I might wanna get into, I'd say just read the docs. Seriously, you'll find it there.